# Outlook is removing my Google Calendar whenever I open an Exchange calendar item. How do I troubleshoot this?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I have a local installation of Microsoft Outlook on a pretty standard Windows 10 computer. Outlook removes all of the four Internet Calendars defined in my profile, as shown in the GIF below, every time I:

1. View all of my calendars in any of the calendar views; and also
2. Open any calendar event on an Exchange account

I have observed this in:

- Safe Mode
- In a "fresh" profile
- As administrator and also not as administrator
- Whether or not they are selected for display.
- The calendars return to availability after Outlook is closed and then reopened, without my needing to edit any account information.

Where to I begin to troubleshoot this? Is there a known behavior or cause? Is there a workaround?

[image: Illustration of behavior]

```
Outlook version 2004 (Build 12730.20270 Click-to-Run)

Windows 10 Pro Version 1909 (but the problem also existed with 1809)
```

There are five mail accounts configured. The accounts are

```
 - Three Microsoft Exchange accounts
 - Two GMail accounts, connected over IMAP
 - Four "Internet Calendars", using the google.com "private" ics links provided by Gmail accounts
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is this a problem that has only recently occurred? If so, what specific operations did you do before this problem occurred?

According to your description,it seems that this issue may be related to your four Internet Calendars. To further confirm your issue, you may try to temporarily remove these four Internet Calendars and add another Internet Calendar to see if the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Why would it be related to the Internet Calendars if an Exchange item opening event triggers their removal?

Comment: (It has persisted as a problem for around two years.)

Comment: According to the GIF you provided, when you click to open any event in those four Internet calendars, all four Internet calendars will disappear. I tried adding the google.com "private" ics links to my Outlook client to test and they can all work fine. So, it seems that your issue maybe related to the four Internet Calendars.

To troubleshot your issue, you may open events in "My calendars" and see if the issue has any difference. Also, if convenient, you may try to temporarily remove these four Internet Calendars and add another Internet Calendar to see if the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: It's when I click to open Exchange events. Events on the Internet Calendars don't trigger the problem when I open them.

Comment: As for specific operations, I basically open Outlook, navigate to the calendar view, and open an Exchange calendar item.

Comment: The calendars were also syncing with an error "Outlook cannot parse the property 'TRIGGER'", but otherwise working OK except for this problem. When I followed the instructions at https://www.mysysadmintips.com/windows/clients/888-outlook-google-calendar-sync-error-cannot-parse-the-property-trigger to define them in outlook.office.com instead of in the desktop client, both problems vanished. (Could you edit your answer to include this, so I can remove the mistaken downvote and credit you with the thinking that got me there? I basically did what you recommended! :-) )

Comment: And... I come to find out that doing things that way makes the Google calendars read-only in Outlook... there appears to be no way to "win"